# ¿Como guardo los resultados de un autocomplete en un input, django1.11?

Tags: javascript, django

Mi problema es que ando usando un autocomplete para relacionar un modelo en Django 1.11. Hasta ahorita ese autocomplete me busca, pero quiero que el resultado me lo guarde en un input. Ese autocomplete lo ando usando en un registro. Espero y me ayuden.

**Vista**

```
def Autocomplete1(request):
if request.is_ajax:
    search=request.GET.get('start','')

    doctores=Solicitante.objects.filter(nombre__icontains=search)

    results=[]
    for doctor in doctores:
        doctor_json={}
        doctor_json['label']=doctor.nombre+" "+doctor.apellido
        doctor_json['value']=doctor.nombre+" "+doctor.apellido
        results.append(doctor_json)

    data_json=json.dumps(results)

else:
    data_json='fail'
mimetype="application/json"
return HttpResponse(data_json,mimetype)
```

**Funcion Javascript**

```
$("#tags5").autocomplete({
    minLength:2,
    source: function(req, add){
        var search=$("#tags5").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/registro/autocomplete1/',
            async:false,
            dataType:'json',
            type:'GET',
            data:{ 'start': search,},
            success: function(data){
                var suggestions=[];

                $.each(data, function(index, objeto){
                    suggestions.push(objeto); 
                });

                add(suggestions);
            },
            error:function(err){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**El input del Formulario**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="tags5">Ajax con GET: </label>
        <input id="tags5" name="relacion">
    </div>
</div>
```